# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'loc.protocol')

Tags: javascript, react-native

My react native app successfully builds and installs, but I'm getting the following error in the simulator:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'loc.protocol')

Full error output / stack trace:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'loc.protocol')
>
> url
>
> url.js:29:29
>
> lookup
>
> index.js:44:19
>
> SocketConnection#constructor
>
> Connection.js:17:26
>
> Connection.js:66:19
>
> loadModuleImplementation
>
> require.js:322:6
>
> useStore.js:5
>
> loadModuleImplementation
>
> require.js:322:6
>
> guardedLoadModule
>
> require.js:201:45
>
> observer$argument_0
>
> Connecting.js:16:8
>
> observer$argument_0
>
> Connecting.js:9:51
>
> useObserver$argument_0
>
> mobxreactlite.esm.js:319:27
>
> reaction.track$argument_0
>
> mobxreactlite.esm.js:292:20
>
> trackDerivedFunction
>
> mobx.module.js:761:28
>
> Reaction.prototype.track
>
> mobx.module.js:1795:42
>
> reaction.track$argument_0
>
> mobxreactlite.esm.js:290:17
>
> useObserver$argument_0
>
> mobxreactlite.esm.js:318:23
>
> renderRoot
>
> [native code]:0
>
> runRootCallback
>
> [native code]:0
>
> renderApplication
>
> renderApplication.js:52:52
>
> runnables.appKey.run
>
> AppRegistry.js:116:10
>
> runApplication
>
> AppRegistry.js:197:26
>
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>
> [native code]:0

The error is being caused by the socket.io-client package (version 2.1.1). The following code is causing the error (url.js:27):

> // default to window.location
>
> loc = loc || global.location;
>
> if (null == uri) uri = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host;

It seems the global.location variable is undefined, but I'm not sure why that's the case. I'm using Xcode and the iPad Pro (9.7-inch) simulator, but I'm getting the same error on Android.

Comment: pls try `loc = loc || global.location || window.location;`

Comment: @Ariel Same error :/